# ArcGIS Pro 1 year home use says I'm not authorized

Tags: installation, license, arcgis-pro, arcgis-personal-use

I just downloaded and installed the ArcGIS 10.3 and ArcGIS Pro 1 year home use. ArcGIS 10.3 is working fine. However, I have to sign into esri online when I initiate ArcGIS Pro. When I sign in using my esri account I bought the product with, I get this:

[image: fail]

I can't seem to locate any information in my install email or online about how to register for ArcGIS Pro. I'd think that since it's bought and paid for through the account it would be connected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be part of an 'organization'  http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/manage-licenses.htm for ArcGIS Pro

> The ArcGIS for Home Use comes with one named user and 100 service
>   credits for ArcGIS.com, however **you will need to contact customer
>   service in order to activate your organization**.

ArcGIS for Home Use is currently issuing the incorrect type of subscription

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/120498

contact esri support